# SQL query WHERE condition is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the query when I input in SQL Server.

```
SELECT * FROM CSPJDE.DBO.Emp WHERE Dept = '010'
```

This is the code in the aspx.cs file

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [dbo].[F4101] WHERE IMSRP3 ='"+Div+"'"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The "Div" variable was transferred from another page where the user will select the dropdown list. Each option has its own value.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DivDrop" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1">
        <asp:ListItem Value="010" Selected="True">(010) CAL</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="020">(020) Sales</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="'030'">(030) Marketing</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="'031'">(031) Admin</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="'035'">(035) Accounting</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="'999'">ALL</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

In the index.aspx.cs file, the code to save the variable for transferring to resultpage.aspx.cs is:

```
 protected void RunButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ResultPage.aspx?Value="+DivDrop.SelectedValue);
    }
```

In the result.aspx.cs, the code to retrieve the variable is:

```
 public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Value"] != null)
        {
           string Div = Request.QueryString["Value"].ToString();
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }
```

Thus, I am unsure as to why the WHERE condition doesn't work. Is my coding wrong or is there something that I have missed out? Please advice. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After comparing the result of the SQL query and my database, I realized that the variable is empty. The reason why it is still able to extract data from the database is because there are empty data in the column I am conditioning.

**EDIT**

Not sure whether this will help but I have an error which might be the cause of this problem. "The name 'DivDrop' does not exist in the current context". DivDrop is the drop down list which I am using to get my value.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ' character from the DropdownList, ie: 030, 031, 035, 999. You're passing Div as '030' and will be translated to WHERE IMSRP3 = ''030''

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DivDrop" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1">
    <asp:ListItem Value="010" Selected="True">(010) CAL</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="020">(020) Sales</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="'030'">(030) Marketing</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="'031'">(031) Admin</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="'035'">(035) Accounting</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="'999'">ALL</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I did that and there seems to be no change to the result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make three changes for your code to work, namely:

1. You need to remove the single quote characters (') from the `Value` property of ALL the drop down list items - `<asp:ListItem Value="'030'"`
2. You are not passing `div` through as a parameter to the `BindGrid()` method. Change your method to be like this:

   ```
   private void BindGrid(string div)
   {
       string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString;
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [dbo].[F4101] WHERE IMSRP3 ='" + div + "'"))
           {
               using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
               {
                   cmd.Connection = con;
                   sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                   using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                   {
                       sda.Fill(dt);
                       GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                       GridView1.DataBind();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Lastly change the `Page_Load` event to pass through the query string value to the `BindGrid()` method:

   ```
   public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string Div = String.Empty;

       if (Request.QueryString["Value"] != null)
       {
           Div = Request.QueryString["Value"].ToString();
       }

       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
            this.BindGrid(Div);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The result is still the same as before. I am not sure what the problem is. I checked the data with my database and realized that div = ''. This is where I am confused as the code clearly shows that it grabbed the value from the dropdown list, however, there was no value.

Comment: Place a break point at your code and debug it.Take the SQL query which gets generated by `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [dbo].[F4101] WHERE IMSRP3 ='" + div + "'"))` and paste it in SQL Server Management Studio and see if it returns any results.Learn to debug your code

Comment: I have already tried to debug it and tried the code in SQL Sever Management Studio. Unfortunately, the code works in the Management Studio. So my guess would be that the variable is empty. For the column that I have conditioned, there are empty data inside it.

Comment: If you tried to debug it then why are you guessing if the variable is empty or not?The debugger will show you the answer.If the query works in SQL and returns data it will return the same data in C#

Comment: Right now, I am certain that the variable was empty and I am trying to find out the reason why. Even though, I have already selected the option in the drop down list that has a value in it.

Comment: Add this to your code before you call Redirect - `string test = DivDrop.SelectedValue;` place a break point on this value and make sure that it has a value.If it has a value you need to place a break point on `if (Request.QueryString["Value"] != null)` and find out why it's empty